# How to use RxJava's repeatUntil operator?

Tags: android, rx-java

I've failed to find documentation on RxJava's repeatUntil operator. Could anyone please provide an example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example:

```
someObservable.repeatUntil(new BooleanSupplier() {
    @Override
    public boolean getAsBoolean() throws Exception {
        return false; //repeat when upstream Observable calls onComplete
        return true;  //don't repeat and go downstream
    }
});
```

Official RxJava javadoc is [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/). `RepeatUntil` description is [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#repeatUntil-io.reactivex.functions.BooleanSupplier-).

Answer (score 2):

An example that prints consecutive numbers every 500ms twice:

```java
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final long startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .take(5) //takes the first five emissions from the observable source
            .repeatUntil(() -> System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis > 5000)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

        Thread.sleep(6000);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
```